# ruby glob for one-level subfolders

Tags: ruby, compass-sass

How can I write glob that will match files only if one-level subfolders? I have a structure like that: `src/items/item-name/file.ext`

And I need a glob that will match only these files, not `src/items/item-name/subfolder/file.ext`. I tried to use `src/blocks/*/*.*`, but it still looks into subfolders.

I'm trying to set up watch action for Compass, and I have to do it with ruby. I'm not familiar with it, and can't find a way to do that myself.

Comment: if you just try: `files = Dir['src/items/*/*.*']`

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby, you can catch all the files following the pattern `*.*` in all subfolders of `src/items` as following:

```
Dir.glob('src/items/*/*.*').select({ |f| File.file?(f) }).each do|file|
  puts file
end
```

It doesn't dig deeper (if you don't use `**` it doesn't do it recursively ), and it only considers file thanks to `File.file?` (in case of a subsubfolder name would match the pattern `*.*`).

Comment: Get the `if` out of the body with `Dir.glob('src/items/*/*.*').select { |f| File.file?(f) }.each do ...`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it again, but I think I used the same glob as you suggest, bit I still had to check file depth analyzing it's path. I have to double-check your suggestion!

Comment: @Anton Try it, it shouldn't go into subfolders.